# Map a single property from one object to another using JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I am using JPA to interact with my postgres database.

I have the following situation: I have two objects - Users and Items, and in my Items Object, I simply want the userId of the User, not the entire User object in the Item.

For example, my User POJO:

```
public class User {

    @Id
    private String userId;

    @OneToMany
    private Item item;

}

public class Item {

    @Id
    private String itemId;

    @ManyToOne
    private String userId;

}
```

How can I just get the User's userId in my Item object?

Thanks.

Comment: (1) Why are you using strings for IDs? (2) *Why* do you want the string ID instead of a reference to the `User` object?

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
class User {
  @OneToMany
  private Collection<Item> items;
}

class Item {
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  @ManyToOne
  private User user;
}
```

you can add a `userID` property to the `Item` entity and map it to the `user_id` column. The following will work:

```
class Item {
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  @ManyToOne
  private User user;

  @Column(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private String userID;
}
```

You need to map the synthetic attribute with `insertable = false, updatable = false` because two attributes are mapped to the same column and we need to make sure that SQL queries contain the column name only once.